LCD display connection without a resistor
Can run a LCD without a potentiometer or a resistor?
I don't have any.
Here it said to connect both:


It appears you circled the 220 ohm resistor used to limit the current to the LED back light. Unless you are using a constant current power supply, you generally need to use a current limiting resistor when powering an LED.
If you do not have a resistor, leaving this out should not stop the LCD from displaying properly under normal ambient lighting conditions. However, in a dark room, the LCD will not have a backlight.
The potentiometer is necessary to adjust the LCD contrast. At the extreme settings, most LCD pixels are either all transparent or all opaque.
Using an Arduino PWM output in an attempt to simulate a voltage between 0 and Vcc may be possible. But likely the PWM output should be passed through a filtering capacitor circuit to reduce the signal to only the DC component before connecting this to the LCD's contrast control pin. This option is discussed in this electrical engineering stack exchange Q/A.

Will it work properly in a normal room if I exclude the potentiometer and resistor?

Maybe you should buy OLED version there is no backlight (at all) and no contrast voltage either (potentiometer). You can see something without backlight, but without reasonable voltage at contrast pin you might not be able to see anything or black squares.

https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=c7f8bf539794a7f6&sxsrf=ADLYWILGw4lncPp2f8HGUo6pSCWLrZO0NA:1729094875134&q=LCD+display+connection+without+a+resistor&source=lnms&fbs=AEQNm0Aa4sjWe7Rqy32pFwRj0UkWd8nbOJfsBGGB5IQQO6L3J_86uWOeqwdnV0yaSF-x2jopn8p7xL4A1Dm_DA2mNSwQLS8ggX90aupvmBKa3yzs15Xg0CORqcq9l1Ydms6PrRPlmr1bkdnrPQy9Qv8nfJeUp9SNl8pfnFiL4i370Z78HhxKk1Q&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjzssKupJOJAxUqslYBHRodCHYQ0pQJegQIExAB&biw=1422&bih=621&dpr=1.35#
What about this?
they did it by connecting contrast to a digital pin.

Possibly yes, but it'd be better to filter PWM output by R-C Low pass filter :) But it might work

It will likely not work without a potentiometer to adjust the voltage at the contrast pin of the LCD. It will probably not hurt the LCD if you let the contrast pin float. But that decision is up to you. You can use a PWM output to try and simulate a voltage between 0 and Vcc. But you should probably filter that signal with a capacitor. That option is discussed in this electrical engineering stackexchange Q/A.
